# Ajax GET request to Flask service fails and returns strange empty object, but the same URL works when pasting into the address bar

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I have an ajax request via jquery that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    url: '127.0.0.1:5000/runNetwork?schema=moscow&consumer=BUILDING_1',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response, error) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

And this is the service it is trying to GET from, written in flask:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request

app = Flask(__name__)


#Example query: 127.0.0.1:5000/runNetwork?schema=moscow&consumer=BUILDING_1
@app.route('/runNetwork', methods=['GET'])
def run_network():
    summary = request.args.get('schema')
    change = request.args.get('consumer')

    json = jsonify({"schema" : summary, "consumer" : change})
    return json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try to click on the button that executes the ajax request, it fails, and I get a strange object that appears to contain no information:

```
{…}
abort: function abort()
always: function always()
catch: function catch()
done: function add()
fail: function add()
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()
pipe: function pipe()
progress: function add()
promise: function promise()
readyState: 0
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
state: function state()
status: 0
statusCode: function statusCode()
statusText: "error"
then: function then()
__proto__: Object { … }
```

I can expand all these options but they all just contain a `length` and a `name` attribute, the length is always 0 or 1 and the name is just the name of the item in the object being returned (ie `abort` has a `name` attribute called `abort`.

What I find very confusing about this is that nothing seems to be wrong when I copy and paste the exact same URL (`127.0.0.1:5000/runNetwork?schema=moscow&consumer=BUILDING_1`) into the browser, I get the JSON back with no issue.

I really don't know what else to do at this point, there is no other information printed in the flask log.

Something else that I just noticed, the request doesn't even seem to be making it to the server, as the Pycharm console from which I am running the flask server is printing this:

`127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jun/2018 20:46:10] "GET /runNetwork?schema=moscow&consumer=BUILDING_1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Whenever I input the query into the address bar, but it does not appear when I try to access it via an ajax request.

I'm getting frustrated and desperate so I am trying to get something - anything - to come back from the server. I changed the request to be a POST type like so:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

#Example query: 127.0.0.1:5000/runNetwork?schema=moscow&consumer=BUILDING_1
@app.route('/runNetwork', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def run_network():

    foo = request.form['foo']
    json = jsonify({"schema": foo})
    return json


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5005, threaded=True)
```

and

```
$.ajax({
        url: "127.0.0.1:5005/runNetwork",
        method: "POST",
        data: { foo : "bar" },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response, error) {
            console.log(response)
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

and it STILL returns the same error.

## SOLUTION FOUND

It was right under my nose the whole time. The flask server address needs to be prefixed with `http://` in the ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5005/runNetwork",
        method: "POST",
        data: { foo : "bar" },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response, error) {
            console.log(response)
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

The reason it succeeded when pasting it into the address bar is that firefox was being ever-so-helpful and automatically prefixing the address before navigating there.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `DataType` line from the ajax request?

Comment: @Joost: Same thing. It just short circuits to the error, giving me this weird empty object. It's maddening.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a go.

Comment: No need, i finally figured it out, and of course it was right under my nose the whole time. See the edit to the post.

Comment: Well spotted :). Try to use `url = "/runNetwork"` though, because if you ever change your domain or port number, it won't work anymore in its current state.